# How to dynamically accepts user input and process the inputs and render output as a calculated count Using Flask web app

Tags: python, html, numpy, flask

I am developing small web application which accepts user inputs and process the input values and count the output using flask this is the python which is static and already given static inputs are min(unit),max(unit) if user enter the min and max values dynamically it has to count and render as id_count. where x is array contains list of values i need to count the cycles where the min value is bilow 13 and max values is above 18 and bilow 25 in python it is running successfulyy and gives my output as count 4

```
x = np.array([0, 14, 9, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 12, 16, 15, 11, 7, 20, 24, 13, 13,
                   14, 19, 13, 12, 10, 7, 3, 3, 3, 25, 14, 14, 14, 7, 24, 20, 20,
                   21, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 16, 11, 11, 18, 22, 22, 20, 19, 19, 18])
sub_lists = np.split(x, np.where(np.diff(x) < 0)[0] + 1)
id_count = 0
id_list = []
for unit in sub_lists:
    if min(unit) <13 and max(unit)>18 and max(unit)<26  and len(set(unit)) > 1:
        id_count += 1
        id_list.append(unit)
print(id_count)
```

iam new to flask app i dont know how to approach this geeting error while reading count value as output
so far used this

```
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def count(id_count):
    x1 = np.array([0, 14, 9, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 12, 16, 15, 11, 7, 20, 24, 13, 13,
                   14, 19, 13, 12, 10, 7, 3, 3, 3, 25, 14, 14, 14, 7, 24, 20, 20,
                   21, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 21, 16, 11, 11, 18, 22, 22, 20, 19, 19, 18])
    sub_lists = np.split(x1, np.where(np.diff(x1) < 0)[0] + 1)
    count = 0
    id_list = []
    for unit in sub_lists:
      if min(unit) < 13 and max(unit) > 18 and max(unit) <= 25 and len(set(unit)) > 1:
        count += 1
        id_list.append(unit)
        print("count is",count)
        return render_template('index.html',count=count)
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True,port=8086)
```

when user enters min(unit)<13 and max(unit)>18 and max(unit)<=25 it has to give the output as count value

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
<form action="/data" method = "POST">
    <p>enter value from 0 to 13<input type = "text" name = "Name" /></p>
    <p>enter values from above 18 <input type = "text" name = "City" /></p>
    <p>enter value bilow 26<input type = "text" name = "Country" /></p>
    <p><input type = "submit" value = "Submit" /></p>
    <p>the acceleration count is {{count}} </p>

</form>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

how to approach this kindly help to this thanks in adavance

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What do you want to achieve? What error are you currently getting? Where do you think the error is being triggered?

Comment: myself resolved the error